# USB PORT LOCATION

Tags: android, windows, usb, device

How do I get the USB port location of the device in Windows 10 without the device manager? The location for my device is `Port_#0009.Hub_#0001` but I want to automate it.

I would like to run a sequence of commands to get this info.

Comment: What does this have to do with Android?

Comment: It is an android device so fastboot commands might help too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know what the goal of this automation is, here's what you can do:

Run this command in your cmd and search for your USB device:

```
wmic path Win32_PnPEntity get DeviceID, Name
```

This should be written in the following format:
USB\VID_xxxx&PID_xxxx....

Now you can use Powershell to display this value:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_xxxx&PID_xxxx\' -Name LocationInformation
```

Here you should replace "USB\VID_xxxx&PID_xxxx..." with your current ID.

At the end you should get your named USB port.

If the question is meant differently, please specify it.

Comment: Thank you. The above command does not provide the same hub number as it is in the device manager. I found this command helpful: "Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_xxxx&PID_xxxx\' -Name LocationInformation"